# Optimizing JS execution and browser frame rate. setTimeout(..., 0) and setTimeout(..., 1) behave differently

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, settimeout, event-loop

I'm studying browser rendering mechanics and want to be able to optimize different action handling on same event and understand what impacts repaints in these cases.

Here I try to change the style of a span (action 1) and just do something more expensive by incrementing a value in a loop (action 2)

1. I don't understand why span's style change is being delayed (most of the time, but not always too) if I put the second action in `setTimeout` (with 0ms delay set)
2. If `setTimeout`'s delay is set to 1ms it never blocks style change, why is there a difference for 0 and 1 here?
3. If we remove `setTimeout` and keep all the logic in a promise chain it always blocks the span style change, does that mean that chained microtasks that work with synchronous code only are basically same as having a synchronous loop in this case. They are blocking repaints and cannot be used for such optimizations?

P.S. Maybe someone knows a good resource for studying this stuff, mostly optimizing script execution throughout different rendering frames?

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (!evt.target.matches("span")) { return; }
  evt.target.style.color = "red";

  setTimeout(() => {
    const loopTimes = 900000;

    const result = Array(loopTimes)
      .fill()
      .reduce((acc, val, i) => {
        return acc.then((val) => {
          return val + 1;
        });
      }, Promise.resolve(0));

    result.then((endResult) => console.log(endResult));
  }, +evt.target.dataset.timeout);
});
```

```html
<span data-timeout="0">click for red (0ms)</span><br>
<span data-timeout="1">click for red (1ms)</span>
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Chrome specific behavior that certainly appeared very recently when they started deploying [the end of the default *1ms* timeout for `setTimeout`](https://crbug.com/402694).
[Here is a comment](https://crbug.com/1339674#c9) I received on a related "bug" I opened:

> Chromium's task scheduling executes task queues in two ways: `PostImmediateTaskImpl` and `PostDelayedTaskImpl` [[1]](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/task/sequence_manager/task_queue_impl.cc;l=369?q=task_queue_impl.cc&ss=chromium), `setTimeout(fn2, 0);` in the test case is treated as post immediate task [...]

This means that `setTimeout(fn, 0)` is now with some kind of ultra high priority and will always get executed before the next animation frame (which happens generally right after a click event because mouse events are throttled to the screen refresh rate).

But from your question I have the feeling that you are actually wondering on an higher level how the rendering happens.
So a little recap, (native) Events are fired from [tasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task), which are queued in task queues from which the event-loop will choose the one to execute at each of its [iterations](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop).
Some of these event-loop iterations are special in that the monitor sent a V-Sync signal and the browser knows it can pass new data to it. This is what we  call a [*rendering frame*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering).
In this *rendering frame*, the browser will execute a few specific callbacks (like animation frame callbacks, resize or scroll events, CSS animations, a lot of other stuff and more importantly to us, the actual rendering of the page.
When you do block the event-loop, the browser can't do all that it was supposed to do in the *rendering frame*, it has to wait for your script to be over (or if it takes too long it may kill it eventually).
Since the *click* event is fired close enough to the next *painting frame*, 1ms timeout is enough to let the browser enter once the *rendering frame* before your scripts block it.

Regarding microtasks, they have their own *microtask-queue*, which is visited every time the JS callstack is emptied, so after each callback (and in some other places of the event-loop). Once this queue is visited, it will exhaust all the microtasks in it before returning back to the event-loop, even the ones that were added during this checkpoint. So indeed, something like `function lock() { Promise.resolve().then(lock) }` would lock the browser just like a `while(1) {}` loop.

But note that `setTimeout` is almost unrelated to the rendering phase of the event loop.

If you are interested in the rendering, then you'll want to hook *animation frames*, and to do so, you can use the `requestAnimationFrame()` method, which will schedule a callback to fire right before the rendering happens.

From there, even Chrome's weird `setTimeout(fn, 0)` will happen only after the rendering:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  // wait the next animation frame
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (!evt.target.matches("span")) { return; }
    evt.target.style.color = "red";

    setTimeout(() => {
      const loopTimes = 900000;

      const result = Array(loopTimes)
        .fill()
        .reduce((acc, val, i) => {
          return acc.then((val) => {
            return val + 1;
          });
        }, Promise.resolve(0));

      result.then((endResult) => console.log(endResult));
    }, +evt.target.dataset.timeout);
  });
});
```

```html
<span data-timeout="0">click for red (0ms)</span><br>
<span data-timeout="1">click for red (1ms)</span>
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer, I wouldn't have found the different ways "immediate" and "delayed" tasks are executed in chromium for sure.