Why setTimeout is executing this way
Code:


setTimeout(() => console.log("1"), 1000)

const startTime = Date.now()
while (Date.now() - startTime < 5000);

setTimeout(() => console.log("2"), 0)
setTimeout(() => console.log("3"), 0)



The output of this sample is:
2
3
1

Why it works this way ?
In this example the loop blocks the thread for 5 seconds or so. At this moment first setTimeout should have been finished and go out of the macrotask queue first, but it doesn't.

Put a console.log() before and after the for loop and you'll see that they appear instantly. Because the body of the loop is empty it executes very quickly, hence no thread blocking.

@RoryMcCrossan check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/n0vqmd4u/

FYI/FWIW: Output on Firefox 130.0.1 (64-bit) is 1 2 3

@DarkBee haha, that's interesting. On chrome it's – 2 3 1, on Safari and Firefox it's – 1 2 3

@VadimSheremetov given that example I would assume that the loop blocks the thread in such a way that the timeouts #2 & #3 are first added to the execution queue before the callback to #1 fires, hence they appear first. This is all just guesswork based on the presentation of the output though. Do you have a specific issue with this, as this is all a theoretical issue which is entirely dependent on the JS implementation of each browser.

This appears to be a side effect of setTimeout optimisation in Chromium, but I can't find documentation that specifically would make this a bug. Quite the opposite, setTimeout does not guarantee execution order.
If you change the timeouts to 1ms it works as you expect:


setTimeout(() => console.log("1"), 1000)

const startTime = Date.now()
while (Date.now() - startTime < 5000);

setTimeout(() => console.log("2"), 1)
setTimeout(() => console.log("3"), 1)



It looks like, in Chromium at least, setTimeout has an optimisation on 0ms to skip checking for timed out actions, and instead just runs them on the next loop (like requestAnimationFrame would) before checking for any other expired timeouts.
Arguably this is desirable behaviour when using a 0ms timeout, and I don't think it's a bug because there's no guarantees on the timeouts - that's in the spec.
I'd recommend using requestAnimationFrame over setTimeout(..., 0) for consistency.

Original answer....
Your problem is that this:
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {}
}

Is not a slow operation. Most JS engines can optimise loops and additions like this.
You can use await to stall your execution and come back:


/** Wait for the given millseconds */
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('1'), 1000)

  await wait(5000);

  setTimeout(() => console.log('2'), 0)
  setTimeout(() => console.log('3'), 0)
}

demo();



But, that doesn't block the JS - you'll get 1 after 1000ms and then wait 4 more seconds for 2 and 3.
If you want to block the executing JS that's harder, as they've worked very hard to remove blocking actions. For instance fetch doesn't support it, and while XMLHttpRequest has an async=false flag you could use to block while downloading something large, I think some browsers ignore that now.

Check out the example, it's changed and I block the thread via while + Date.now().
The output is the same.

@VadimSheremetov hmm, this appears to be a Chromium thing. If you set the timeouts on 2 and 3 to 1ms they fire in order. Chromium (and not FX) must optimise setTimeout to run on the next microtask loop when 0ms.

@Yogi others have identified it https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40849848#comment10

@yogi and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73387191/905

In Chrome, the event loop appears to prioritize the execution order based on when callbacks are queued, even if a timer has expired. So in Chrome, the tasks scheduled with 0 delay (2 and 3) are executed immediately once the loop ends, and then the 1 callback (which was delayed by 1000 milliseconds) is executed afterward.
Firefox, on the other hand prioritizes the execution of overdue timers when the event loop becomes free, so it logs 1 first (because its delay has already passed) and then logs 2 and 3, which were scheduled with 0 delay but queued after the loop.
So in actuality it is the different browser strategies of prioritization that makes the difference here.

On your computer 10,000 * 10,000 is taking less than 5 seconds.

Doesn't really matter how much it takes. Just make sure it runs for more than 1 second.

I get the same result, even when I ensure that it takes more than 5 seconds: https://jsfiddle.net/n0vqmd4u/
